# Saving an image from bytes

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an API which will save an image at a given location .

Below is my Code for that

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\img-logo.jpg");
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])(new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
                string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                Save_Application_Image("12004", str);
```

and the method in API

```
  public void Save_Application_Image(string staffCode , string bytearray)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bytearray);
            file_path = "~/uploads/" + file_name;
            FileStream file = File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(file_path));
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            file.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
        }   
    }
```

This api has to be called from Android Application so I will receive two string parameter.

It is saving the file perfectly but file is not readable. No preview for image file.

What is the right approach for this ?

Comment: Why are you using `ASCII` instead of `UTF8` (or probably even better, `Base64`? Web API can also receive `byte[]` automatically, so there's no even a need to convert to string

Comment: my dear @CamiloTerevinto , that's not the problem , problem is writing it into file which should be readable . I have updated my question with your suggestion .

Comment: The image is not readable because the end result is not exactly the same as the initial data, that's why I suggested changing encoding

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , ok . Any suggestion how to do it ?

Comment: Not related to ASP.NET (or MVC or WebAPI) - this is depends only on which imaging or Windows-UI framework you use with the image class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of how the `ImageConverter` works, but I've used this before to convert `Image`s to `byte[]`:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\img-logo.jpg");
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(stream);
    string savedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    Save_Application_Image("12004", str);
}
```